# cannot install node forever globally

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, forever

I'm trying to install forever globally by

> npm install forever -g

but it says "

> Error: EACCES: permission denied, access
>   '/usr/local/node-v9.9.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules

so I did

> sudo npm install forever -g

which works and tried

> /usr/local/node-v9.9.0-linux-x64/lib/node_modules/forever/bin/forever
>   start server.js

and then my website has a http breakdown. it appears the /usr/local directory had the ownership changed to the sshuser. This is preventing http from functioning. Any ideas, help please?

Note: im using ssh in root access

Comment: That's probably **not** a thing that you really want to install "globally", and certainly not in the "system installed instance" of nodejs as this appears to be. You'd probably be better off looking at something like `nvm` to manage environments, and at the very least consider you probably really want this installed "per project" only, rather than "global". There other other ways to set the "per project" path to executable scripts.

Comment: Also 9.x is not a release that will ever be on the LTS schedule. It's the development "tick" of the cycle, so for any production environment you really want one of the [LTS releases](https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule). If it's for your own development, then all the more reason for an environment manager like `nvm`.